# Get Selected Record from ListView

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvvm, kendo-ui, telerik

I'm using the Kendo UI ListView, using MVVM bindings.  The definition of the listview looks like:

```
<tbody id="listview" data-role="listview" 
       data-template="ListItemTemplate" data-selectable= "true" 
       data-bind="source:categoriesDataSource, events:{change:onListChange}">
```

The rows of the listview are `<tr>` rows bound to the following view model:

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
  categoriesDataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
    data: @(Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.ItemCategories)))
  })
});
```

I'm converting the array of JSON objects directly; this works out great.  However, I also have a change event defined and that gets executed correctly, but I don't know how to grab the values of the currently selected record.  Is there a way to get that from the underlying data source?  I was trying the following event handler in the view model, which the code runs but the values are not of the selected record:

```
onListChange: function(e) {
                this.set("ID", e.data.ID);
                this.set("ParentItemCategoryTypeID", e.data.ParentItemCategoryTypeID);
                this.set("Code", e.data.Code);
                this.set("Name", e.data.Name);
                this.set("IsActive", e.data.IsActive);
                this.set("Sequence", e.data.Sequence);
}
```

How do I get the values of the currently selected record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this I made for u

```
onListChange: function(e) {
  var index = e.sender.select().index();
  var item = e.sender.dataSource.view()[index];
  console.log(item); // item here is the currently selected list item (ObservableObject))
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I had to change this to e.sender, once I did that it worked.  In this case, this was not a reference to the listview, but to the view model.  Using e.sender, that is how I got the reference to the listview.

Answer (score 0):

There is dataItem method to get the data item specified for kendo widgets.
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/listview#methods-dataItem

```
onListChange: function(e) {
  console.log(e.sender.dataItem(e.sender.select()));  
}
```